# Find a gameObject with name and a component inside the gameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to find a gameObject by its name and then get component of that gameObject.
For eg:

```
GameObject Go;
InputField GoInput;

void Start()
{
  Go = GameObject.Find("TextField"); //which I know
  GoInput = GameObject.Find("TextField").GetComponent<InputField>(); //is this proper because it does not work
}
```

EDIT: Solved it with the above code itself. There was a space between "Text" and "Field".

Comment: Your code is correct. Could you explain what leads you to think it doesn't work? Do you get `null` inside `GoInput`?

Comment: Ah there was a space in the text "Text Field". It is all fine and working now :)

Comment: Next time please be specific about the error instead of saying "it does not work". It helps people helping you and you'll get more accurate answers :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
InputField GoInput = GameObject.Find("TextField").GetComponent("InputField") as InputField;
```

Comment: That's not the answer. `GetComponent("InputField") as InputField` is a (somewhat discouraged) equivalent of `GetComponent<InputField>()`.

Comment: @hugo ah, that's the only method change I could think of. Maybe the variables need to be properly initalized inside of the start function